# pandasで1変数の情報を用いて2変数を作成したい

Tags: python, pandas

dfにおけるｘには、目的地までの来るまでの車での移動時間、または徒歩分数が混在しています。
index 2には、徒歩分数が入っています。
車での移動時間が入っている箇所では、「車x(ykm)」という形式になっています。
xから、車での移動時間を示すcar_timeと徒歩分数walk_timeの二つの変数を作成したいです。
現在は次のような状況ですが、walk_timeの、index=1, 2の部分に0が入りません。
私が、正規表現が分かっていないからだと思いますが、ご教示くださいますとありがたいです。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['車5(0.8km)', '5', '車27(8.6km)']},
    index=[1, 2, 3])

# 車時間のみを取り出し、欠損値には0をうめる。
df['car_time'] = df.x.str.extract(r'車(\d*)').fillna(0)
#　徒歩分数のみを取り出し、欠損値には0を埋める
df['walk_time'] = df.x.str.extract(r'(\d*)').fillna(0)

print(df)
```

出力結果：

```
            x car_time walk_time
1   車5(0.8km)        5          
2           5        0         5
3  車27(8.6km)       27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r'(\d*)'` だと空文字列にもマッチしてしまいます。1桁以上の数字から始まる文字列のみにマッチさせるために `r'^(\d+)'` などとすると良いです。

作業途中の `df.x.str.extract(＊＊＊)` あたりを `print` してみると `NaN` があるかないかが分かるので、違いに気づけます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘の点について、下記のコマンドを実行しましたが、index1の車5の「5」、index 3の車27の「27]も含まれてしまいます・・・
df['walk_time'] = df.x.str.extract(r'(\d+)').fillna(0)

Comment: @kazusumi 回答を更新しました。

Comment: 排他的論理和の演算子^の役割が分かりました! コメントをありがとうございます。

Comment: @kazusumi 多くの正規表現では単なる `^` は「行頭」にマッチします(他の役割が付くときもあります)。[この記事](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE#basic_regular_expression.EF.BC.88BRE.EF.BC.89)などに解説があります。`^` は文字としては「ハット」や「キャレット」などと呼ばれています。これについては[このWikipedia記事](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A0%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9)をご覧ください。（念の為書いておきますと、今回の文脈では排他的論理和自体とは関係ありません。）

Comment: ご指摘、勉強になります！ありがとうございました。